# cross compile project as buildroot package with waf for ARM9

Tags: c, cross-compiling, waf, buildroot, library-path

I am using Code sourcery g++ lite toolchain 2013.

Got a project which I integrated into buildroot (which seems to be fine, everything gets called as expected).

`waf` is the buildsystem of choice

```
define EEBUSRESTIFIED_CONFIGURE_CMDS
(cd "$(@D)"; \
$(TARGET_CONFIGURE_OPTS) \
CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD)" \
LDFLAGS="--sysroot=$(STAGING_DIR)" \
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$(STAGING_DIR)" \
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/lib/pkgconfig" \
PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR="$(STAGING_DIR)" \
./waf --dest=$(TARGET_DIR) configure)
endef
```

shows

```
Setting top to                           : /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/build/foo-6508f5b36172ba8965372ef96fb350b413ec5d15 
Setting out to                           : /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/build/foo-6508f5b36172ba8965372ef96fb350b413ec5d15/build 
Checking for program gcc,cc              : /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc 
Checking for program ar                  : /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar 
Checking for program glib-genmarshal     : /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/glib-genmarshal 
Checking for program perl                : /usr/bin/perl 
Checking for 'glib-mkenums'              : /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/glib-mkenums 
Checking for program glib-compile-schemas : /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/glib-compile-schemas 
Checking for program pkg-config           : /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/pkg-config 
Checking for pkg-config version >= '0.26' : yes 
Checking for 'glib-2.0'                   : yes 
Checking for 'glib-2.0' version           : yes 
Checking for 'gobject-2.0'                : yes 
Checking for 'libsoup-2.4'                : yes 
Checking for 'libsoup-2.4' version        : yes 
Checking for 'libxml-2.0'                 : yes 
Checking for 'uuid'                       : yes 
Checking for endianness                   : little 
Checking for inline                       : inline
```

which looks fine.

At the compile step

```
define EEBUSRESTIFIED_BUILD_CMDS
(cd "$(@D)"; \
$(TARGET_CONFIGURE_OPTS) \
LDFLAGS="--sysroot=$(STAGING_DIR)" \
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$(STAGING_DIR)" \
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/lib/pkgconfig" \
PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR="$(STAGING_DIR)" \
./waf --dest=$(TARGET_DIR) build)
endef
```

it dies with

```
/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: warning: library search path "/usr/lib" is unsafe for cross-compilation
/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: warning: library search path "/usr/lib" is unsafe for cross-compilation
/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

*I understand the issue* - `waf`/`ld` tries to link against my host libs, which is doomed to fail.

**How can I fix ld to pick up proper library paths? What is the source of this problem?**

---

Here the expanded output of the build command (replaced spaces by linbreaks):

```
echo
"PATH="/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/bin:/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin:/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/sbin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/core_perl"
AR="/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar"
AS="/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-as"
LD="/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld"
NM="/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-nm"
CC="/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc"
GCC="/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc"
CPP="/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-cpp"
CXX="/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++"
FC="/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gfortran"
RANLIB="/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib"
READELF="/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-readelf"
STRIP="/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-strip"
OBJCOPY="/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objcopy"
OBJDUMP="/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objdump"
AR_FOR_BUILD="/usr/bin/ar"
AS_FOR_BUILD="/usr/bin/as"
CC_FOR_BUILD="/usr/bin/gcc"
GCC_FOR_BUILD="/usr/bin/gcc"
CXX_FOR_BUILD="/usr/bin/g++"
FC_FOR_BUILD="/usr/bin/ld"
LD_FOR_BUILD="/usr/bin/ld"
CPPFLAGS_FOR_BUILD="-I/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/include"
CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD="-O2
-I/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/include"
CXXFLAGS_FOR_BUILD="-O2
-I/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/include"
LDFLAGS_FOR_BUILD="-L/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/lib
-L/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/lib
-Wl,-rpath,/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/lib"
FCFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=""
DEFAULT_ASSEMBLER="/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-as"
DEFAULT_LINKER="/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld"
CPPFLAGS="-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE
-D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64"
CFLAGS="-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE
-D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64

-pipe
-O2
"
CXXFLAGS="-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE
-D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64

-pipe
-O2
"
LDFLAGS=""
FCFLAGS=""
PKG_CONFIG="/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/bin/pkg-config"
PERLLIB="/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/lib/perl"
STAGING_DIR="/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot""

I tried a couple of combinations for `PKG_CONFIG_*` , with/without `--sysroot` but no success so far.
```

Already read [linux cross compiling and dynamic libraries / linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502603/linux-cross-compiling-and-dynamic-libraries-linking)

For reference, the whole `foo.mk`

```
FOO_VERSION = abcd1234
FOO_SITE = ssh://git@some.where/FOO
FOO_SITE_METHOD = git
FOO_LICENSE = unknown
FOO_INSTALL_TARGET = YES
FOO_DEPENDENCIES = util-linux libglib2 libsoup libxml2 host-pkgconf

define FOO_CONFIGURE_CMDS
    echo "$(TARGET_CONFIGURE_OPTS)"
    (cd "$(@D)"; \
    $(TARGET_CONFIGURE_OPTS) \
    LDFLAGS="--sysroot=$(STAGING_DIR)" \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$(STAGING_DIR)" \
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/lib/pkgconfig" \
    PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR="$(STAGING_DIR)" \
    ./waf --dest=$(TARGET_DIR) configure)
endef

define FOO_BUILD_CMDS
    (cd "$(@D)"; \
    LDFLAGS="--sysroot=$(STAGING_DIR)" \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$(STAGING_DIR)" \
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/lib/pkgconfig" \
    PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR="$(STAGING_DIR)" \
    ./waf --dest=$(TARGET_DIR) debug)
endef

define FOO_INSTALL_TARGET_CMDS
    (cd "$(@D)"; \
    ./waf --dest=$(TARGET_DIR) install)
endef

define FOO_CLEAN_CMDS
    (cd "$(@D)"; \
    ./waf --dest=$(TARGET_DIR) distclean)
endef

$(eval $(generic-package))
```

Comment: Try replacing `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` with `PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR`.

Comment: Replaced it both in configure and build - no change

Comment: Also tested premutations with removing `--sysroot` and/or `PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR` - no success

Comment: No expert on waf, but the "dodgy" `*_FOR_BUILD` vars should be due to the lack of `echo "$(TARGET_CONFIGURE_OPTS)"` in `FOO_BUILD_CMDS`. However, if this would be a autotools based configuration and install I wouldn't be overriding much in the build state, so try having just `(cd "$(@D)";  ./waf --dest=$(TARGET_DIR) debug)` in `FOO_BUILD_CMDS`. Moreover, replace `PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/lib/pkgconfig"` with `PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/lib/pkgconfig:$(STAGING_DIR)/lib/pkgconfig:$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"`.

Comment: Holy crap, I just ripped of all options and it went through like butter... thanks a million! Make your last comment a answer, and I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: But it ends up wit a `x86_64` binary instead of a ARM binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a `make clean` a `make all` I finally got a solution - the trick is to pass flags via LDFLAGS concerning `sysroot` to the linker.

`file` tells me `./build/foo.bin: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, not stripped` which looks quite good.

Below the `foo.mk` used

```
FOO_VERSION = 6508f5b36172ba8965372ef96fb350b413ec5d15
FOO_SITE = ssh://git@some.where/FOO
FOO_SITE_METHOD = git
FOO_LICENSE = unknown
FOO_INSTALL_TARGET = YES
FOO_DEPENDENCIES = util-linux libglib2 libsoup libxml2 host-pkgconf

define FOO_CONFIGURE_CMDS
    (cd "$(@D)"; \
    $(TARGET_CONFIGURE_OPTS) \
    LDFLAGS="-Wl,--sysroot=$(STAGING_DIR) -Wl,--verbose=9 -Wl,--error-poison-system-directories -L$(STAGING_DIR)/lib -L$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/lib" \
    ./waf --dest=$(TARGET_DIR) configure)
endef

define FOO_BUILD_CMDS
    (cd "$(@D)"; \
    ./waf --dest=$(TARGET_DIR) debug)
endef

define FOO_INSTALL_TARGET_CMDS
    (cd "$(@D)"; \
    ./waf --dest=$(TARGET_DIR) install)
endef

define FOO_CLEAN_CMDS
    (cd "$(@D)"; \
    ./waf --dest=$(TARGET_DIR) distclean)
endef

$(eval $(generic-package))
```

---

For reference - the linker output

```
GNU ld (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2011.09-70) 2.21.53.20110905
  Supported emulations:
   armelf_linux_eabi
   armelfb_linux_eabi
using internal linker script:
==================================================
<< stripped manually >>    
==================================================
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/crt1.o succeeded
/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/crt1.o
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/crti.o succeeded
/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/crti.o
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/crtbegin.o succeeded
/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/crtbegin.o
attempt to open src/asyncrequestobj.c.1.o succeeded
src/asyncrequestobj.c.1.o
attempt to open src/cache.c.1.o succeeded
src/cache.c.1.o
attempt to open src/error.c.1.o succeeded
src/error.c.1.o
attempt to open src/main.c.1.o succeeded
src/main.c.1.o
attempt to open src/request-info.c.1.o succeeded
src/request-info.c.1.o
attempt to open src/response-info.c.1.o succeeded
src/response-info.c.1.o
attempt to open src/xml_helper.c.1.o succeeded
src/xml_helper.c.1.o
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libgobject-2.0.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libgobject-2.0.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so succeeded
-lgobject-2.0 (/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so)
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libglib-2.0.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libglib-2.0.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so succeeded
-lglib-2.0 (/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so)
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libglib-2.0.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libglib-2.0.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so succeeded
-lglib-2.0 (/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so)
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libsoup-2.4.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libsoup-2.4.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libsoup-2.4.so succeeded
-lsoup-2.4 (/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libsoup-2.4.so)
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libgio-2.0.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libgio-2.0.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so succeeded
-lgio-2.0 (/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so)
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libgobject-2.0.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libgobject-2.0.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so succeeded
-lgobject-2.0 (/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so)
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libglib-2.0.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libglib-2.0.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so succeeded
-lglib-2.0 (/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so)
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libxml2.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libxml2.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libxml2.so succeeded
-lxml2 (/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libxml2.so)
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libuuid.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libuuid.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libuuid.so succeeded
-luuid (/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libuuid.so)
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/libgcc.a succeeded
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libgcc_s.so succeeded
opened script file /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libgcc_s.so
opened script file /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libgcc_s.so
attempt to open libgcc_s.so.1 failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 succeeded
libgcc_s.so.1 (/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
attempt to open libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/libgcc.a succeeded
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libpthread.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libpthread.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libpthread.so succeeded
opened script file /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libpthread.so
opened script file /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libpthread.so
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libpthread.so.0 succeeded
/lib/libpthread.so.0 (/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libpthread.so.0)
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a succeeded
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libc.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libc.so succeeded
opened script file /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libc.so
opened script file /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libc.so
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libc.so.6 succeeded
/lib/libc.so.6 (/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libc.so.6)
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a succeeded
(/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a)elf-init.oS
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/ld-linux.so.3 succeeded
/lib/ld-linux.so.3 (/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/ld-linux.so.3)
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/libgcc.a succeeded
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libgcc_s.so succeeded
opened script file /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libgcc_s.so
opened script file /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libgcc_s.so
attempt to open libgcc_s.so.1 failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 succeeded
libgcc_s.so.1 (/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
attempt to open libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgcc.a failed
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/libgcc.a succeeded
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/crtend.o succeeded
/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/crtend.o
attempt to open /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/crtn.o succeeded
/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/crtn.o
libpcre.so.1 needed by /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so
found libpcre.so.1 at /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libpcre.so.1
librt.so.1 needed by /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so
found librt.so.1 at /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/librt.so.1
libffi.so.6 needed by /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so
found libffi.so.6 at /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libffi.so.6
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 needed by /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libsoup-2.4.so
found libgmodule-2.0.so.0 at /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0
libresolv.so.2 needed by /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libsoup-2.4.so
found libresolv.so.2 at /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libresolv.so.2
libz.so.1 needed by /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libsoup-2.4.so
found libz.so.1 at /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libz.so.1
libm.so.6 needed by /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libsoup-2.4.so
found libm.so.6 at /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libm.so.6
libsqlite3.so.0 needed by /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libsoup-2.4.so
found libsqlite3.so.0 at /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0
libdl.so.2 needed by /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libsoup-2.4.so
found libdl.so.2 at /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libdl.so.2
ld-linux.so.3 needed by /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libuuid.so
found ld-linux.so.3 at /home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/usr/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/ld-linux.so.3
/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: warning: library search path "/usr/lib" is unsafe for cross-compilation
/home/bernhard/buildroot-2013.08/output/host/opt/ext-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: warning: library search path "/usr/lib" is unsafe for cross-compilation
```

At the very end you still can see that the wrong paths are present, but by passing the `-L` flags which seem to have a higher priority it still works as supposed

---

---

---

I found the root cause - when doing a

```
bld.program(features = ['c', ..],
        libpath = ["/usr/lib"],
        stlibpath = ["/usr/lib"],
        includes = ["src", "/usr/include"],
        target = "foo.bin",
        source = ["main.c","foo.c"])
```

`libpath`, `stlibpath` and `includes` (at least porbably more) are *NOT* prefixed with `destdir` -- also the options should be `--destdir` instead of `--dest`

Comment: I was avoiding to write you that solution because what you are doing is essentially ignoring pkg-config existence, and that, in the end, makes the system harder to maintain. Trade-offs, as sometimes pkg-config can be a PITA to get right in cross-compilation environments (as you just seen!). But it works! :)

Comment: I am not really happy about doing it that way, but for now this has to suffice, pkg-config actually was not the culprit here (I added debug output which would just call pkg-config for all my libs and the `-L` paths were all correct). So the lookup issue resulst from somewhere else - maybe linker scripts?

Comment: That is definitely the strange part for me, because indeed pkg-config seems well... configured. However, as you correctly stated, at least originally the linker was trying to use non-arm libs which indicates an incorrect set of library paths. Well, glad it's now working!

Comment: Updated answer just now

Answer (score 1):

No expert on waf, but the "dodgy" `*_FOR_BUILD` vars should be due to the lack of echo `"$(TARGET_CONFIGURE_OPTS)"` in `FOO_BUILD_CMDS`. However, if this would be a autotools based configuration and install I wouldn't be overriding much in the build step, so try having just

```
define FOO_BUILD_CMDS
    echo "$(TARGET_CONFIGURE_OPTS)"
    (cd "$(@D)"; \
    ./waf --dest=$(TARGET_DIR) debug)
endef
```

Moreover, replace `PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/lib/pkgconfig"` with `PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/lib/pkgconfig:$(STAGING_DIR)/lib/pkgconfig:‌​$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"`.

Comment: Reverted, it then compiles for the build machine (x86_64), not the target (ARM9)

Comment: Then try adding the `echo "$(TARGET_CONFIGURE_OPTS)"` like I did to my answer. It's quite strange that the build systems loses sight of that..

Comment: Tried that as well – failed too.